# Identifying road segments completely cut off by polygon using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, topology, network, road

I have a road network (black line) and I want to identify all segments that are completely cut off by my flood polygon (blue polygon).

I have clipped the road network to get all roads *within* the road network and I have been able to identify *some* road segments that are cut off by the flood zone polygon (green lines and pink lines), but not all of them. I did this through a combination of the 'intersection' tool and the 'Spatial Query' plugin.

I'm using QGIS for this.

[image: Identifying roads cut off by flood zone polygon]

I used the 'Topology Checker' tool to identify all 'dangles' but it highlights road segments that are, for example, just dead ends but *are* connected to the wider road network. I guess I'm looking for 'double dangles'?

I'm basically looking for road segments that are completely disconnected from the larger road network but they can be connected to one another. 'Dangle islands'?

If an agent is placed on a 'dangle island' and is ***not*** able to access the full network, then that road network is a 'dangle island'!

[image: Some of these 'dangles' do connect to the wider road network]

Comment: Is this road network a geometric network?

Comment: @Barbarossa: yes, it is a geometric network. At least I think it is! I've been using it for routing. It is an OS MasterMap® Integrated Transport Network downloaded from Ordnance Survey.

Comment: It is more than line geometry, such as a shapefile.  A geometric network will be comprised of nodes, lines, and connectivity rules used to model their behavior.  it's hard to determine from the ITN website whether it is or not.  Can you verify?

Comment: how about a concave hull on the flood polygon then selection? or fill the flood polygon holes and then perform the selection with roads? If I understand correctly you need to get rid of the gaps.

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/minimum-bounding-volume.htm

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/filling-holes-in-selected-polygons.htm

Comment: mh I can think of a few multi-step, unintuitive or workaround options...the issue is there's no trivial way to declare some part of your network(s) the *main* network. are you willing to go PostGIS by any chance?

Comment: @Barbarossa: apologies! This is just the shapefile of the road network. I have created a separate geometric network that I'm using for routing.

Comment: @ThingumaBob I don't have any PostGIS experience I'm afraid.

Comment: One technique I use when facing the same problem, but with river networks and their skeletons, is to take the largest connected patch of network as the "main" network. This is usually done in raster space, although a vector analogue should not be difficult. May not work generally for you, but something to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I add a quick solution using *Virtual Layers* to get all roads split by the flood polygon that are within the convex hull of the same.
Load your layers in QGIS, open a new *Virtual Layer* via `Layer -> Add Layer -> Add/Edit Virtual Layer`, select both layers via `Import` and run

```
SELECT <column1>,
       <column2>,
       ST_Difference(a.geometry, b.geometry) AS geometry
FROM <road_layer> AS a
JOIN <flood_layer> AS b
  ON ST_Within(a.geometry, ST_ConvexHull(b.geometry));
```

The resulting set of (split) roads should represent those that are isolated by the flood polygons inner rings.
They wil not have an 'island' reference, i.e. they are not grouped by their individual connectivities into small networks.
Also, the join on `ST_Within` excludes road segments that are not fully within the polygons outer boundary and thus might lead to missing segments on border cases. If that is of concern, you can get the `ST_Intersection` of the roads with the convex hull in a subquery first.
Another caveat might be the convex hull itself by not following an inward curved boundary. Try with `ST_ConcaveHull` if you find any of those cases significant.
More precision can be achieved with `ST_ExteriorRing` and polygonizing the resulting LineString.
It depends on your polygon how to best proceed with getting rid of the inner rings.
Hope that helps. Get back with any errors, I can't test right now.